# Ajax readyState always 1

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm tying to do what seems like a simple ajax but can't get it to work. Here's my code:

```
var xmlHttpRequest;

function processRequest(){
 alert("process request called with " + xmlHttpRequest);
 if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState==4){
  alert("status = " + xmlHttpRequest.status);
  if(xmlHttpRequest.status == 200){    
     }
   } else {
    alert("process request no luck readyState = " + xmlHttpRequest.readyState);
   }
 alert("process request exiting");
}


function updateCount(customerID, productID) {

 xmlHttpRequest = init();

  function init(){

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
               return new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } else {
         alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        }
  }


 xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", url, true); 

 xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = processRequest(); 
}
```

Like I said in the subject line, readyState is always 1. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!
Eddy

Answer (score 2):

You are calling processRequest before you start your request.

```
xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = processRequest();
```

is wrong and has to be

```
xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
```

This will store a reference to your method instead of calling it directly.

As soon as the ready state changes, the `xmlHttpRequest` object trys to call this reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for both Ghnommy and digitalFresh! It works beautifully. I was struggling to figure out where is the blocking / waiting being done by this API. I guess javascript works in mysterious ways :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `xmlHttpRequest.send();` after  `xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = processRequest;`.