# Javascript / Ajax (no jquery!) onreadystatechange stays 1

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, onreadystatechange

I'm writing a simple ajax function:

```
1 function setXMLHttpRequest() {
2     var xhr = null;
3     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
4         xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
5     }
6     else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
7         xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
8     }
9     return xhr;
10 }
11
12
13 var xhrObj = setXMLHttpRequest();
14 function get_commenti(id)
15 {
16     var url = "get_commenti.php?id="+id;
17     xhrObj.open("GET", url, false);
18     xhrObj.onreadystatechange = add_commenti(id);
19     xhrObj.send(null);
20 }
21 
22 function add_commenti(id)
23 {
24     if(xhrObj.readyState == 4)
25     {
26         var id_div = "commento_"+id;
27         document.getElementById(id_div).innerHTML += xhrObj.responseText;
28     }
29     alert(xhrObj.readyState);
30 }
```

the problem is that the readystatechange alerted on line 29 is always 1 and never 4.
If i visit the page <"get_commenti.php?id="+id> with  my browser it prints off the results as expected (i also tried putting an absolute path).

I have tried looking the problem up but it seems as nowadays everyone is using jQuery and I'm not yet.

It might be worth noting that I am running this on my own web server, so maybe it is because of something I have configured?

thanks!

Comment: Where are you calling your functions?

Comment: and what browser are you in?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094997/ajax-readystate-always-1
try to change this `xhrObj.onreadystatechange = add_commenti(id);` with `xhrObj.onreadystatechange = add_commenti`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not assigning the function

```
xhrObj.onreadystatechange = add_commenti(id);
```

You are calling it.

You need to use a closure.

```
xhrObj.onreadystatechange = function() { add_commenti(id); };
```

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance. This did it. Now I understand the problem. Thanks all for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Properties

`onreadystatechange` should not be used with synchronous requests.
Just use the response right after the ajax request

```
function get_commenti(id)
 {
     var url = "get_commenti.php?id="+id;
     xhrObj.open("GET", url, false);
     xhrObj.send(null);
     var id_div = "commento_"+id;
     document.getElementById(id_div).innerHTML += xhrObj.responseText;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `if (xhrObj.readyState == 4 && xhrObj.status == 200)` try that instead maybe ?

Comment: problem is that I was calling the function instead of assigning it